# Shibboleth External Authentication Security issues

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on, csrf, shibboleth

When integrating Shibboleth Identity Provider to use an external Authentication system. The flow goes as below:

1. Shibboleth Idp redirects the user to external System to Authenticate.
2. User Authenticates in the external system.
3. User is redirected back to Shibboleth Idp (say POST request)
4. Shibboleth Idp proceeds to generate valid SAML response for the user.

In the above case there are opportunities for a malicious user to impersonate a different user by creating a modified POST request in Step 3 and the Idp would authenticate him unless some validation is performed.

The only 2 ways of validation I can think of is:

1. Use some distributed shared session between the Idp and Authentication System. So that Idp can verify from the session, whether the user was authenticated.
2. Use some signing mechanism on the POST request parameters(say a private key of Authentication System is used to sign the hash of the userId) and the Idp can verify the POST request is genuinely redirected from the Authentication System and not forged by the user.

Are these the common approaches to resolving such security loopholes ?

Also do both of these methods sufficiently bypass all potential loopholes ?